# How to filter out this special pattern using python re.findall?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find out some special keywords in a long strings.
Here are the example:

```
long_str = '''
TX[03]
rqn : 0x73
cqn : 0x12
packets : 888
encap : 0
csumNone : 0
csumOk : 0
lroPackets : 0
lroBytes : 0
wqeErr : 0
RX[12]
rqn : 0xa6
cqn : 0x2a
packets : 123
encap : 0
csumNone : 0
csumOk : 0
lroPackets : 0
lroBytes : 0
wqeErr : 0

RX[13]
rqn : 0xa9
cqn : 0x2c
packets : 456
encap : 0
csumNone : 0
csumOk : 0
lroPackets : 0
lroBytes : 0
wqeErr : 0'''
result = re.findall('RX\[\d+\].*packets\s+:\s+(\d+)', a, re.DOTALL)
```

But the `result` is `['456']`, which is not the same as my expected `['123','456']`.

How can i fix my re pattern to filter out the expected values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to make it lazy:

```
RX\[\d+\].*?packets\s+:\s+(\d+)
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cUQHmB/1).
Otherwise, your `.*` construct eats up ***the whole string*** and backtracks afterwards (succeeding when it finds the last `packets`, that is).

---

Another one would be:

```
RX\[\d+\]\n
(?:.+\n){2}
packets\D+(\d+)
```

See [**this one working here**](https://regex101.com/r/cUQHmB/3) (and mind the different modifers!).

Comment: Great~  thanks for your two solutions. BTW,  the regex101.com is really a good website. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, the `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `<a> b <c>`, it will match the entire string, and not just `<a>`. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using the RE `<.*?>` will match only `<a>`.

Similarly in your case, `result = re.findall('RX\[\d+\].*?packets\s+:\s+(\d+)', a, re.DOTALL)` would give the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. :)